# Variable to be treated as string

Tags: php

I have some issues with appending the right text to my **array.php** file.
So basically I want to make  **$array[]** to be treated as a **string** and **$_POST['delete']** to be **variable**. Unfortunately I don't know how to escape the quotes properly.

```
$open = fopen("array.php", "a");
fwrite($open, "$array[] = '$_POST['delete']';");
fclose($open);
```

I want the final result to be something like:

 $array[] = 'the text from input form';

Comment: change `fwrite($open, "$array[] = $_POST['delete']");` to `fwrite($open, '$array[] = '.$_POST['delete']);`

Comment: I just edited my post, can you check again?

Comment: try `fwrite($open, '$array[] = '."'{$_POST['delete']}'");`

Comment: have you tried adding backslash before the `$`? to `fwrite($open, "\$array[] = '$_POST['delete']';");`

Comment: Chetan Ameta, thanks a lot!!! :)))))))))))) It worked like charm!

Comment: Do you realize that `the text from input form` might become malicious code? Example: `whatever'; echo 'Malicious code executed`